# Angular 8 - Extend Data Grid of DevExpress library

Tags: angular, devextreme, devextreme-angular

I need to extend the DxDataGridComponent, but I'm not able to understand how it works.

First of all I will extend the DxDataGridComponent:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DxDataGridComponent } from 'devextreme-angular/ui/data-grid';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-data-grid',
  templateUrl: './data-grid.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data-grid.component.scss']
})

export class DataGridComponent extends DxDataGridComponent {
  constructor(..) {
    super(..);
  }
}
```

Now I'm stuck because this component required these parameters:

```
constructor(elementRef: ElementRef, ngZone: NgZone, templateHost: DxTemplateHost, _watcherHelper: WatcherHelper, _idh: IterableDifferHelper, optionHost: NestedOptionHost, transferState: TransferState, platformId: any);
```

What should I do? What is the correct way to extend this component?

I'm doing this, because I have to add some custom @Input, but I want also all the default parameters of DxDataGridComponent.

Someone can help me?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I'm also struggling to extend the Datagrid component

Answer (score 0):

Well seems there is already an open discussion about this in their Support Center:

https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/Ticket/Details/T278278/is-there-a-way-to-extend-devextreme-sontrols

And here you can find a demo in Plunker:

http://embed.plnkr.co/rCAGIkRdnJaXKiZqrA7L/

Basically your constructor should inject all needed parameters that later should be passed to the `super()` call, eg:

```
constructor(
    private eRef: ElementRef, 
    ngZone: NgZone, 
    private templateHost: DxTemplateHost, 
    private _watcherHelper: WatcherHelper
)
{
    super(eRef, ngZone, templateHost, _watcherHelper);
}
```